# NullPointerException on DialogFragment at onResume()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onresume, dialogfragment

I have a a DialogFragment that has this particular onResume code to handle the back press.  Unfortunately my code keeps generating that NullPointerException (I'm catching it) but I don't know why it's happening.  This happens every time the DialogFragment is opened.  Thanks for the input on this particular case.

```
@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    try
    {
        getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,android.view.KeyEvent event) 
            {
                if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
                {
                    dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                else return false; 
            }
        });
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        Log.w("NullPointerException", "HealthRecords.java : onResume()",e);
    }
}
```

My LogCat Error:

```
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010): HealthRecords.java : onResume()
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at digitalbeef.com.home.HealthRecords.onResume(HealthRecords.java:132)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-21 15:47:20.266: W/NullPointerException(17010):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You dont need to handle the back button. Dialogs do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because `onResume` is called before `onCreateDialog`. Therefore `getDialog` returns null.

What you want to do is to set the listener once the dialog is created, or even *when it's created*:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                             android.view.KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                dismiss();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I see now and understand the error was the order of the @Overrides.